# JavaScript HTML Template Literal Indenting

Tags: indentation

I have https://github.com/Quramy/vim-js-pretty-template installed to handle syntax highlighting for template strings marked with `/*html*/`

But indenting does not work correctly - I end up with something like

```
const someHtml = /*html*/`
  <div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  </div>
  `
```

Is there a way to make vim realize the string literal's contents need to be indented like html?